Slow Navigation and Poor Performance in Next.js 15 App Router with Prisma and PostgreSQL
Title:
Slow Navigation and Performance Issues in Next.js 15 with App Router and Prisma

Description:
I’m building an e-commerce application using:

Next.js 15 (App Router)
Prisma with PostgreSQL
Hosted on Vercel

The project includes:

Admin Dashboard

Demo
Repo


Storefront

Demo
Repo




The Problem:
Both the admin dashboard and storefront experience 3–5 second delays before navigation, especially:

Dashboard Components: Parallel data fetching still causes delays.
Storefront Filters: Filtering categories by pushing values to search params is slow.


What I've Tried:

Implemented Parallel Data Fetching.
Optimized Prisma queries following best practices.
Debugged bundle sizes and rendering bottlenecks.

However, performance issues persist both in development and production.

Observations:

In the storefront, navigating to the cart and checkout (using Zustand) works almost instantly.

Here's a Network tab screenshot showing navigation delays:


And the Performance tab showing slow rendering:




Questions:

Is the App Router inherently slower for such cases?
Could my data fetching approach or Prisma integration be the issue?
How can I debug and fix this delay effectively?


What Works Well:
Cart and checkout navigation (Zustand state management) works quickly, even when the rest of the app lags.

Additional Context:

Storefront filtering updates URLSearchParams but still feels slow.
No custom Vercel optimizations applied yet.

Any help in identifying bottlenecks or improving performance is appreciated!

try to add a loading indicator to your routes. The delay might be caused by slow database queries.

@NullEe the queries happen in page.tsx files, i can't use useState in them, Can console.time do the job?

sure you can do that. also you can add a loading.tsx file in same directory as your page.tsx to handle a loading page.
find more info in next js docs. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming

yes, you're right, when adding loading.tsx files it navigates instantaneously and show loading components

can this be due to the database i use?
I use Neon.tech, I'm from Egypt and the Database region is AWS Asia Pacific (Singapore)

it can be a reason. there might be several reason for this. you have to find out which is it. but in this case next js it self is the last one for sure.

yes, i'll search about this, thanks
